# Does the following integral converge: $\int_6^{\infty}\frac{dx}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}$

Tags: calculus, integration, convergence-divergence, definite-integrals, improper-integrals

> Does the following integral converge: $$\int_6^{\infty}\frac{dx}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}$$

I suppose we have to solve such problems by comparison test.

All the integrals I tried so far do not fit the test.

Can anyone show how to approach this.

Comment: Why won't you just evaluate it?

Comment: @nsanger: Actually, ${\text{arcsinh}}' (x) = 1/\sqrt{1 + x^2}$. $\arcsin' (x)$ is $1/\sqrt{1 - x^2}$.

Answer (score 6):

You have, for $x>0$,
$$
\sqrt{1+x^2}\leq \sqrt{1+2x+x^2}= \sqrt{(x+1)^2}=x+1
$$
thus
$$
\int_6^\infty\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}dx\geq \int_6^\infty\frac{1}{x+1}dx=\infty
$$
and your integral is divergent.

Answer (score 4):

Notice that

$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}\sim_\infty\frac 1x$$
so the given integral is divergent.

Answer (score 2):

If you evaluate the integral using the substitution $$x=tan(\theta)$$

the result is integration of $$sec(\theta)$$ with changed limits of integration and if evalueted completely it tends to infinity

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Clearly, $x>6>1>0$, therefore $\underbrace{\sqrt{0+x^2}}_x<\sqrt{1+x^2}<\underbrace{\sqrt{x^2+x^2}}_{x\sqrt2}$.